# How to dynamically change text color based on input string in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to dynamically change the text color for a sensor input (that generates depth levels from 0 to 10 as a float number) based on the value, I am getting the value through python (which I am using to generate the HTML) as a string since converting to a digit was causing a lot of errors. How do I change the color for this string dynamically based on its value?

My idea was to detect only the first digit and determine the color based on that since the values are floats from 0 to 10, however, I have not been able to do that so far using JS.

How do I change the color dynamically between white, black and red depending on the sensor value which is a string?

The value of the "depth" below (which is the string mentioned above) I am passing from python to the HTML using JS.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="bottom-left">
        <h6><span id="depth">Bottom Left</span>
        </h6>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    left: 30px;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: "the value"...what value is that? "python"...what python? We don't understand what this value is, where it comes from, or how it relates to any of your HTML and CSS. Are you using Python to generate the HTML? Please clarify the question. We cannot see your screen, we can only understand you based on the information in your question. Right now there is not enough information or context for us to be able to help you. Thanks.

Comment: so what is the input as string, can you add the different input you get and for each input what is your expected color

Comment: Sorry I edited it out, what i am trying to do basically is manipulate a string that is a number based on its value. I had trouble converting it to a float so I wanted to use only the first digit from the string as a reference to change the color for example, 0.23 then based on the first character being 0 the text would be red and so on.

Comment: Just as a HTML tip, you dont need to do `<h6>` or any `H` tag, followed immediately by a span or label or anything else. Just keep the `h` tag as it is, and if you want it styled differently, use `h6 {}` in your css to style it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the input number via python would have some range, you can convert that number in JS using [parseFloat](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) and take a module 10 and the Math.floor to get it within the range of 0-9. Then you could use a switch case and assign a class that will be applied to the span at run time.

```
let inputNumberSring = '456.321',
    inputNumber = parseFloat(inputNumberSring),
    classIdentifierNumber = Math.floor(inputNumber % 10),
    selectedClass = '';

switch(classIdentifierNumber){
    case 0: selectedClass = 'white-background'; break;
    case 1: selectedClass = 'red-background'; break;
    case 2: selectedClass = 'red-background'; break;
    case 3: selectedClass = 'white-background'; break;
    case 4: selectedClass = 'yellow-background'; break;
    case 5: selectedClass = 'white-background'; break;
    case 6: selectedClass = 'white-background'; break;
    case 7: selectedClass = 'yellow-background'; break;
    case 8: selectedClass = 'white-background'; break;
    case 9: selectedClass = 'red-background'; break;
    default: selectedClass = 'white-background';
}

$('#depth').removeClass().addClass(selectedClass);

.white-background {
   color: white;
}
.red-background {
   color: red;
}
.yellow-background {
   color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following example you can find how to change the text color when the value of the select change, this is just to give you an example on how to accomplish your requirement.

```js
document.querySelector("select").addEventListener("change", e => {
  if(e.target.value <= 3){
    document.querySelector("#depth").style.color = "green"
  } else if(e.target.value <= 6){
    document.querySelector("#depth").style.color = "blue"
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#depth").style.color = "pink"
  }
})
```

```css
.bottom-left {
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="bottom-left">
        <h6><span id="depth">Bottom Left</span></h6>
    </div>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for changing the color based on the value ou generate on HTML

You'll usee `parseInt` to extract the integer value from the string

```js
var sensorValue = document.getElementById("value").textContent;
sensorValue = parseInt(sensorValue);
var text = document.getElementById("depth");
if (sensorValue < 3) text.style.color = "green";
else if (sensorValue < 6) text.style.color = "yellow";
else text.style.color = "red";
```

```css
.bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <span id="value">4.23543234</span>
   <div class="bottom-left">
      <h6 id="depth"> Bottom Left
      </h6>
   </div>
</div>
```